# Filtrar en Pandas con una lista de palabras "python"

Tags: python, pandas, condiciones, filtro

mi pregunta es la siguiente:
si tengo un DataFrame en pandas como este (Mucho mas extenso por supuesto, pero como ejemplo sirve):

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'Nom':'Peter', 'Edat':'28'},
                  {'Nom':'Joan', 'Edat':'60'},
                  {'Nom':'Rufus', 'Edat':'45'},
                  {'Nom':'Peter', 'Edat':'28'},
                  {'Nom':'Peter', 'Edat':'28'}], index=list('12345'))
```

---

Como ejemplo quiero crear un segundo Df filtrando por los nombres "Peter" y "Rufus".

Hasta donde yo se lo haria asi:

```
df[(df['Nom'] == 'Peter') | (df['Nom'] == 'Rufus')]
```

y funciona, pero mi duda es si existe ***alguna manera de pasarle una lista*** con palabras para filtrar.

he probado esto(entre otras) y no funciona:

```
df[df['Nom'] == ['Peter', 'Rufus']]
```

Me da este error:

> ValueError: ('Lengths must match to compare', (5,), (2,))

A ver si me podeis ayudar :)

Comment: Podés usar [el método isin de las series](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html)

Comment: Carai, es perfecto! Gràcias